# installing packages in AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I'm trying to install [Google Tink](https://github.com/google/tink/) in AWS EMR 5.28.0 without much luck.
It looks like the AWS EMR image is rather strange in nature.  Any ideas?

```
sc.install_pypi_package("tink")
```

error: Could not find bazel executable. Please install bazel to compile the Tink Python package.

```
 sudo yum install -y bazel3
```

Requires: java-11-openjdk-devel

```
sudo yum install java-11-openjdk-devel
```

No package java-11-openjdk-devel available.

```
 sudo yum install amazon-linux-extras
```

No package amazon-linux-extras available.

Comment: What repositories do you have enabled?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't know how to enable repositories?

Comment: You are new to Linux? Start with the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#package-repository).

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have enabled sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel. No change, I would have thought jdk is a pretty common package.

Comment: What about all the other repos?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes how do you install them? I can't see anything in the aws doc

Comment: Now you know about yum-config-manager. You can use that to inspect the state of the system and make any necessary changes.

Comment: @MichaelHampton that's not a useful comment

Comment: I am not here to read documentation for you. You should have already read about yum-config-manager and learned what you can do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the Linux AMI (The base for AWS EMR 5.28.0) is a pain to work with.  None of the available repositories have Java, Bezel, much less Tinker readily available (compare to Macos, Ubuntu, or even ECR Python image where it's a breeze)

To get Java 11jdk you need to go to Oracle and look for Linux x64 RPM Package.  Unfortunately you need to sign in to their site so wget/curl is not possible.

To install you need to do:

```
 sudo yum localinstall jdk-11.0.12_linux-x64_bin.rpm
```

For Bazel you need to get the package from Github https://github.com/bazelbuild/.   Pick the latest and install

```
./bazel-4.1.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
```

Then pip works fine

```
sc.install_pypi_package("tink")
```

Output:

```
Successfully built tink
Installing collected packages: protobuf, absl-py, tink
Successfully installed absl-py-0.13.0 protobuf-3.17.3 tink-1.6.1
```